# Augmenting image in tensorflow 1 cause to have an tensor in return

Tags: tensorflow

I want to augment my images without using keras. I came across with that website: https://www.wouterbulten.nl/blog/tech/data-augmentation-using-tensorflow-data-dataset/

The problem is that I give and images as input but take tensor as outpput (which was not the case using keras imagegenerator). How can I deal with that? After augmenting the data, I want to have same type of object in return.

Comment: After augmenting the images, just use the `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` to construct a `tf.data.Dataset` object. Use this object to train your model.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow provides image augmentation in two ways, one s using tf.keras preprocessing libraries and other one is using tf.image.
Use the following sample code with tf.image performing image augmentation.

```
def augment(image_label, seed):
  image, label = image_label
  image, label = resize_and_rescale(image, label)
  image = tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad(image, IMG_SIZE + 6, IMG_SIZE + 6)
  # Make a new seed
  new_seed = tf.random.experimental.stateless_split(seed, num=1)[0, :]
  # Random crop back to the original size
  image = tf.image.stateless_random_crop(
      image, size=[IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3], seed=seed)
  # Random brightness
  image = tf.image.stateless_random_brightness(
      image, max_delta=0.5, seed=new_seed)
  image = tf.clip_by_value(image, 0, 1)
  return image, label
```

Follow the [Tensorflow image augmentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation#using_tfimage) tutorial for information.